# Function Not Recognized When Receiving Job Multiple Times in Loop

Tags: powershell

This is my first time using Jobs in powershell. I have placed a function into a job and I have a while loop which displays an ETA countdown. I want the countdown to pause/adjust if it reaches a predefined time and the function hasn't finished processing.

I have created the countdown successfully, but trying variations of `Receive-Job` and `Get-Job`. I have also made a global variable which changes from 0 to 1 when the function completes. The while loop is currently looking at the variable in an infinite loop until it changes

```
$Completion = "0"
$TWOLength = "10"
$ScanFunction = {InitiateScan -Type "Auto"}
$ScanJob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScanFunction

$iTWO=1
Do {
    $TLlabel.Text = "Scanning Computer        ETA: "+$LoadProVal+" Seconds"
    $TLPB.Value = -($LoadProVal-$LoadProMax)
    $TLform.Refresh()
    $LoadProVal--
    $iTWO++
    $TLform.Refresh()
    Start-Sleep 1
}
While ($iTWO -le $TWOLength)

While ($Completion -ne "1"){
    #Do Loop Infinite until Variable Changes
    Receive-Job $ScanJob -Keep
    Write-Host $InitialScan
        Start-Sleep 5
}
```

When that code runs I get the error message `The term 'InitiateScan' in not recognized` once it starts processing the `Receive-Job $ScanJob -Keep` While loop.
If I put the `Receive-Job` before the While loop the error doesn't occur which is why I added the -Keep parameter

The desired end result should be:

   -Start Scan in Job

   -Start Countdown

   -When reach `$TWOLength`, check job `$Completion` Variable

   -If `$Completion` not 1, wait and check again

   -If `$Completion` is 1, end loop and move on

Comment: The function previously ran inline with the rest of the code without any issues. It was only put into the Job because as it was processing, the loading bar would become unresponsive.

Comment: So `. InitiateScan -Type "Auto"` wouldn't work?

Comment: What if the function was in it's own file? can I call it differently then?

Comment: No, `. ` (dot-sourcing) wouldn't work directly, though you could write the function definition to a file and then dot-source it from the background process; however, there's a simpler solution - please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For a background job to see a *function*, it must be defined as part of its script block (or be part of an auto-loading module / imported from a module).
- Background jobs run as separate PowerShell processes (that don't load the user's `$PROFILE`).

One option is to **pass the function's *definition* to the script block to execute in the background and *redefine* it there**.
Note that you must similarly redefine other functions, if any, that this function calls.

A simplified example:

```
# Define the function to use in the background job.
function Initiate-Scan { "hi: $args" }

# Start the job and (re)define the function in the script block, via
# passing the function body as an argument.
$jb = Start-Job { 
  ${function:Initiate-Scan} = $args[0]; Initiate-Scan -Type Auto 
} -Args ${function:Initiate-Scan}

# Get the job's output.
Receive-Job $jb -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

The above yields `hi: -Type Auto`, demonstrating that the function was successfully redefined in the background job.

---

An **alternative** is to define the functions in a script block passed to the **`-InitializationScript` parameter**:

```
# Define the function to use in the background job.
function Initiate-Scan { "hi: $args" }

# Start the job and (re)define the function in the initialization script
# script block, so that the main script block can use it.
$jb = Start-Job -InitializationScript (
    [scriptblock]::Create("function Initiate-Scan { ${function:Initiate-Scan} }")
  ) -ScriptBlock { 
    Initiate-Scan -Type Auto 
  }

# Get the job's output.
Receive-Job $jb -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Note: The script block must be created *from a string* with `[scriptblock]::Create()`, because - due to a bug - `$using:` for referencing values from the caller's scope doesn't work as of PowerShell 7.0 - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4530).

Once the bug gets fixed, you could do the following:

```
# !! Doesn't work as of PowerShell 7.0
-InitializationScript { ${function:Initiate-Scan} = ${using:function:Initiate-Scan} }
```